# How can I show, that RSA with OWP is IND-CPA secure by using H function?

Tags: rsa, chosen-plaintext-attack, one-way-function, random-oracle-model

How can I show, that RSA with OWP is IND-CPA secure by using H function , a random oracle model.

The Encryption goes like: $\text{Encryption_H_PK}(M)\gets(C_1,C_2)\gets(f(x),H(x)\oplus M)$

Decryption goes like: $M\gets H(x)\oplus C_2$

Comment: First clarify what's meant by _"RSA with OWP"_ (it's unclear to me: OWP could be an assumed property of RSA); and the relation this (or part of it) has to the question's $f$. Also, figure out how $x$ is obtained in decryption. Then: assume an hypothetical algorithm wining the [CPA game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ciphertext_indistinguishability#Symmetric_IND-CPA_Game,_Formalized), and turn it into one that, with the help of the random oracle, contradicts the hypothesis made on $f$. Conclude by contraposition.

Comment: owp means a one way permutation

Comment: also can you suggest why this does not provide chosen cipher text attack security

Comment: Yes, OWP undoubtedly means one way permutation; the unclear thing is _with_. Is RSA assumed to _be_ a OWP, or is RSA used _with_ some other OWP?

Comment: RSA here is assumed to be a OWP

Comment: CCA security is evaluated per the [IND-CCA games](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ciphertext_indistinguishability#Indistinguishability_under_chosen_ciphertext_attack/adaptive_chosen_ciphertext_attack_(IND-CCA1,_IND-CCA2)). You want to exhibit a method to win the IND-CCA2 game (I think the scheme is IND-CCA1 secure). Hint: $\oplus$ is a group operation.